# How to prevent vim from setting current directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Recently my vim will change current directory no matter what I do. I'm using spf13 distribution and when I am in a rails app root directory and did `vi`, my `pwd` will be correctly in app root directory. But once I open some file, any file, it will change the `pwd` to `abosolute/path/to/myrailsapp/app/assets/stylesheets`,

When I don't have `let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1` in my .vimrc, vim will change the `pwd` to current file directory; When I do, it will change to the stylesheet directory whenever I open a file.

I'm also using `rails.vim` installed. Here is the related code inside my `.vimrc`

```
if !exists('g:spf13_no_autochdir')
     autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^\[A-Za-z0-9\]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif                                                                                         
     " Always switch to the current file directory
endif
```

UPDATE:
What I want: the `pwd` always stay in `absolute/path/to/myrailsapp/`, no changing to the `stylesheet` directory automatically whenever I open a file.

Comment: Use the distribution's issue tracker: Vim with SPF13 is not Vim anymore and the author of that stupid distribution should be the only person dealing with issues related to it.

Comment: I've just switched to Janus. Problem solved!? :) Thanks everyone.

Comment: Janus is just as bad as spf13. If you don't want to take the time to learn and configure your editor, use sublime text.

Comment: I will take the time to learn and config incrementally, just not all at once. Janus looks much more promising for now, especially for rails development. It's even using rake.

Comment: @randomor: in my case, ctrlp.vim was the one changing directories. Using `let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'r'` allows me to stay at the root directory of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found and had a look at the plugin. I assume this is it:

https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc

Around line 75 you can see:

```
" Most prefer to automatically switch to the current file directory when
" a new buffer is opened; to prevent this behavior, add the following to
" your .vimrc.before.local file:
"   let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1
```

So just add that last line (without the comment-marker quote) to your .vimrc and you'll get rid of the automated directory change.

I note that neither method in my other answer would have worked, because the plugin author for whatever reason decided not to use the built-in option, and also not to put their autocmd in a group. Naughty, naughty!

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. However, I was not clear on the question, but if I turn `let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1` on, the `pwd` will point to `absolute/path/to/myrailsapp/app/assets/stylesheets` whenever I opened the first file. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this according to [Ben's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277265/778757).

spf13 loads configuration files [in order as follows](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim#fork-customization).

1. .vimrc.before - spf13-vim before configuration
2. .vimrc.before.fork - fork before configuration
3. .vimrc.before.local - before user configuration
4. .vimrc.bundles - spf13-vim bundle configuration
5. .vimrc.bundles.fork - fork bundle configuration
6. .vimrc.bundles.local - local user bundle configuration
7. .vimrc - spf13-vim vim configuration
8. .vimrc.fork - fork vim configuration
9. .vimrc.local - local user configuration

`if !exists('g:spf13_no_autochdir')` check is done at (7), so `let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1` should be loaded before that.

I put it in .vimrc.before.local, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this could be happening.

The most likely, is that this "spf13" configuration includes `set autochdir`. To find out whether this is the case, start up Vim normally, and type `:verbose set autochdir?` and press Enter. This should tell you IF autochdir is set and WHICH FILE set it to that value.

If autochdir is set, then you only need to set up a VimEnter autocmd, or stick a file in ~/.vim/after/plugin, to turn it off again after spf13 loads.

If autochdir is NOT set, then probably an autocmd is setting your directory for you. If there is a plugin option in SPF13 to turn it off, then do that. If not, you'll need to find where in the plugin the directory is getting changed. If you're lucky, the autocmd will be in an augroup by itself, and you can then remove that autocmd with `:au! GroupName`. This command can be in the same places; a VimEnter autocmd, or a file in ~/.vim/after/plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `autochdir` is not set, but `noautochdir` is set by `ctrlp.vim`. My original question was not clear. But I've updated it. What I really wanted is to not only turn off autochdir and stay in the app root directory, but not change `pwd` to the `stylesheet` directory, which happened out of nowhere even I haven't opened any file from that directory.